# npm ci warns tar invalid entry and throws error as cb never called

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, filesystems, cicd

Our project installs the node_modules using package-lock.json with the help of `npm ci` command.

And this is what we see always:

```
npm WARN prepare removing existing node_modules/ before installation
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tar invalid entry
...
npm ERR! cb() never called!
```

Node version: `14.18.1`

NPM version: `6.14.15`

Environment: `Mac OS Big Sur 11.6.2`

Is this warning to be ignored? Can we suppress this warning and error?

Answer (score -1):

It may be a caching problem it append to me.

- Clean the cache `npm cache clean --force`
- Install the packages `npm install`

EDIT: don't forget to remove the `node_modules/` folder before executing the commands.